# Assistance with nested if statements

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to stackOverflow. I have a question. Why is my code not working...it's nested if statements, that should work...I'm stumped. You are supposed to have money, a home (type 1 to 3) and phone. The phone is the problem. callLine is used to tell which line will be displayed each time callText is called. It adds 1 to itself every time it is called in Calling2. Whenever it gets to a certain number, it changes callText (the text displayed) to something else. But with callWho variable (work or home) it needs to be checked aswell. Here it is:

```
@ echo off
set money=10000
set house=1
set item=Phone
set /a callLine=0
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Hello there! I am Joe, and I am the mayor of Redcrest Town.
pause
cls
echo I'm so happy to see another resident move into the Redcrest Town.
echo So, will you do me a favour and tell me your name?
set /p Name=
cls
echo Well then, %name%! Welcome!
pause
cls
echo I hope you have a great time here. You have 10,000 dollars, and a small house.
echo Please enjoy your time here!
pause
cls
:UsePhone
echo Money: %money%
echo.
echo You are using your phone. This will cost money, each time you call.
echo.
echo.
echo  __i         [CONTACT LIST]
echo ^|---^|      [1: HOME     ] 
echo ^|[_]^|      [2: WORK     ]
echo ^|:::^|    
echo ^|:::^|    
echo `\   \   
echo   \_=_\
set /p callWho=Select Number:
if %callWho% == 2 goto Calling
echo %callText%
pause
:Calling
cls
echo Calling......
ping localhost -n 4 >nul
:Calling2
if callLine == 0 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="Hello? Is this %name%?"
if callLine == 1 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="Oh hello! It's really nice to talk to you again."
if callLine == 2 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="Well, I will see you soon, %name%! Bye!"
if callLine == 3 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="END"
set /a callLine = callLine + 1
cls
echo  __i         
echo ^|---^|       
echo ^|[_]^|   PHONE: %callText%   
echo ^|:::^|    
echo ^|:::^|    
echo `\   \   
echo   \_=_\
ping localhost -n 5 >nul
if %callText% == "END" goto UsePhone
goto Calling2
```

I keep crashing with: . is unexpected at this time....
Really unusual.

Comment: What seems to be the issue with the code? Like, does it not function properly, or does it have an error that you can post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the %% around `callLine`.

```
:Calling2
if %callLine% == 0 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="Hello? Is this %name%?"
if %callLine% == 1 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="Oh hello! It's really nice to talk to you again."
if %callLine% == 2 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="Well, I will see you soon,     %name%! Bye!"
if %callLine% == 3 if %callWho% == 2 set callText="END"
set /a callLine = callLine + 1
```

When testing variables with `if` statements, the variables must be enclosed in % %